# Nested attributes double errors when update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

When I have got two models:

```
Guaranty
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
belongs_to :product
```

And model Product:

```
Product
accepts_nested_attributes_for :guaranties
has_many :guaranties
```

And 2 views ( one view when add Product to Guaranty and Second view Add Guaranty to Product). using fields_for

After update I have got double errors for e.g name: cannot be blank, name: cannot be blank

Comment: Can you show the controller code and the validation definitions in the model..

Answer (score 0):

You should only be accepting nested attributes for children of the parent model, both of your views should consist of forms for the parent with fields_for the children.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent.